# cómo asignar un a valor a una variable a través de su nombre, en Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Estoy utilizando un método que me manda 2 argumentos (valor, nombreVariable)

el nombreVariable es la variable a la que tengo que ingresarle el valor

```
public progress1: number = 0;
public progress2: number = 0;


cambiarValor(valor:number, nombreVariable:string){
     this.[nombreVariable] = valor;
   }
```

Normalmente para querer asignar un valor a una variable se utiliza this.progress1 = valor.

Pero resulta que yo quiero controlar desde la función cual es la variable que quiero cambiar...

Tengo esa duda
Espero su ayuda equipo!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que colocar una propiedad adicional:

```
[name: string]: any;
```

Esto te dará la posibilidad de tener una propiedad "variable" de cualquier tipo, y de esta manera el compilador no te dará error

Codigo completo:

```
class MiClase  {
    public progress1: number = 0;
    public progress2: number = 0;
    [name: string]: any; 
    cambiarValor(valor:number, nombreVariable:string){
        this[nombreVariable] = valor;
   }
}


let miclase : MiClase = new MiClase();
console.log(miclase.progress1); //0
miclase.cambiarValor(2,"progress1");
console.log(miclase.progress1); //2
```

Comment: Realmente es necesario lo del [name: string] : any? lo probe sin eso y no tira errores, perdon quizas es que no entiendo para que sirve.

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego En este caso sirve para engañar al compilardo: demo https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAECyBLAwpKBTWsDewtYAcBXAIzERFgICcB7Ac2vRgEYAuWAOyIFsT1qsALywADAG48+YmQpU6jZlABMHbnwHCxk-LAD0egNqcIPdBygAXaok70AuhwicAnjvwhTJRBGoA1CDBaagAKADdA4LZ1fmoAGi5aPiYAmwgycysbOwBKXF1dSwALRChjJJIU3x8M+y0IoOp3WABfYDbgYDB0S1geCjRMDiRUaEwRTnQAdwQUQZCcyRBaTihaboA6IPoQ-vAxjZoGJlZF-T1RYD3Bjc8+H39I0OU4gCIjxVZXxdAVtc3trsBgcPicoCwzgZlJ0gA

Comment: Ah, no me marcaba el error porque no tenia el tsconfig.json en mi carpeta, faltaba el strict mode

Comment: @Yussef, eres el mejor, con agregar esto [name: string]: any, fue más que suficiente para que lo que quería funcionara y sin alterar el código..

Answer (score 0):

El código está casi bien.

Lo que sucede es que el punto no va cuando accedes a una variable mediante corchetes.

Así debería ser:

```js
let object = {
    progress1: 1,
    progress2: 2,

    cambiarValor: function (valor, nombreVariable){
     this[nombreVariable] = valor
    }
}

console.log(object)

object.cambiarValor(8, "progress2")

console.log(object)
```

Nota que quité las cosas de typescript para que se pueda ejecutar en el snippet.